# Jackson databind read json tri-dimensional array

Tags: java, json, multidimensional-array, jackson, primitive

I want to read a json Array and put it, if possible, into an int tri-dimensional array.

The data will look like this, I can change it's design to suit my needs as it is not done yet. The values are dumb but what is good to know is that (**Caution mindf*ck ahead**) I have to nest an unknown number of arrays containing integers, two times in an array that is repeated three times or less in the root node.

I.E. `int[3 or less][2][unknown int] = val`

I wrote the keys to improve readability, they may or may not be part of the actual json.

```
{
    demand : {
        0 : {
           0 :{
               0 :22,
               1 :32,
               2 :21
            },
            1 :{
               0 :2762,
               1 :352,
               2 :231
            }
        },
        1 :{
            0 :{
               0 :222,
               1 :232,
               2 :621
             },
             1 :{
               0 :272,
               1 :37762,
               2 :261 
             }
         }
     }
}
```

The point is that the keys and values are all integers and I would like to create an `int [][][]` with it. I think that the answer is in this doc : [Jackson Full Databinding](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDataBinding#line-32) but I do not understand properly how it would work for my data.

I'm thinking about some ObjectMapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference>() { })` and will continue to look into this but I don't have much hope.

Thanks for any help!

**Edit** Here is the actual valid JSON

```
[  [   [  22, 32,  21   ],  [ 2762,  352, 231 ] ], [    [  222, 232,  621 ],  [ 272,  37762, 261]] ]
```

Comment: First off, the JSON you describe as wanting is invalid JSON. Keys in JSON are *strings*. Second, Even if we pretend the keys are strings, what you're describing is a Java `Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>>` A three dimentional array in Json would be `[ [ [22,32,21],[2762,352,231] ],[ [222,232], ... ] ] ]`

Comment: Like I said, the keys may or may not be part of the actual JSon data I wrote them for readability purposes. The square brackets notation is indeed the right one for arrays, I'll edit accordingly later. I yet have to find out what to do with Jackson though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Serializing/Deserializing arrays with Jackson is the same as serializing anything else:

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {

        int[][][] a = new int[2][3][2];
        a[0][2][0] = 3;

        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();

        // Serialize to JSON
        String json = om.writeValueAsString(a);
        System.out.println(json);

        // deserialize back from JSON
        a = om.readValue(json, int[][][].class);
        System.out.println(a[0][2][0]);

   }
}
```

output:

> [[[0,0],[0,0],[3,0]],[[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]]]
>   3

That said, unless you know it's always going to be a three dimensional array, you're be better served using `List`s

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solved it. I thought that I could not use `.class` on types that are not objects explicitly defined in a class. I was confused by the Generic types the jackson tutorial talks about. Now that I know what a [generic type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) is I'm back on track.

Comment: @Johnride No worries. Arrays in java are oddball. They are first-class objects and come from a class ... it's just not one you can extend and it has special properties (the index operator).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this answers your question but I think you can always use iterator and split, for instance:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import net.sf.json.JSONObject;

public class test {
    /**
 * @param args
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map <String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    Map <String, Object> map2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    Map <String, Map> map3 = new HashMap<String, Map>();
    map1.put("0","22,32,21");
    map1.put("1", "2762,352,231");
    map2.put("0", "222,232,621");
    map2.put("1","272,37762,261");
    map3.put("0",map1 );
    map3.put("1",map2);
    JSONObject jsonobj = JSONObject.fromObject(map3);  // creating json object
    Iterator it = jsonobj.keys();
    int maxZ = 0; //find out the length of the last dimension
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        JSONObject jobj = (JSONObject) jsonobj.get(it.next());
        Iterator it2 = jobj.keys();
        while(it2.hasNext()) {
            if(((String)jobj.get(it2.next())).split(",").length > maxZ){
                maxZ= ((String)jobj.get(it2.next())).split(",").length;
                }
        }
    }
    int[][][] result= new int [jsonobj.size()][2][maxZ]; //creating 3D array of the right size
    int x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;
    it = jsonobj.keys();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        JSONObject jobj = (JSONObject) jsonobj.get(it.next());
        Iterator it2 = jobj.keys();
        y = 0; //reset y
        while(it2.hasNext()) {
            String[]s =((String)jobj.get(it2.next())).split(",");
            z = 0; //reset z
            for (String str : s) {
                result[x][y][z] = Integer.parseInt(str);
                z++;
            }
        y++;
        }
    x++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < z; k++) {
                System.out.print(result[i][j][k]);
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println("\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
272 37762 261 

222 232 621 

2762 352 231 

22 32 21
```

not sure why this is in the back order, sorry if this doesn't help :P